# Django doesn't go in view method and returns nothing

Tags: jquery, python, django, post, get

```
def search(request):
       print "Here!"
       #some work here
```

In django i have a view method like this. When i call the url associated this view i dont get any error. But "print 'Here!'" doenst work and it returns nothing. Also i have a post method like this.(i request via jquery) 
How ever my index view method returns web page's main page.

---

I have just solve the problem. Url conf was like this :

```
url(r'^$', include('maps.world.urls'))
```

and world.urls:

```
url(r'^$', 'index', name = 'world-index'),
url(r'^save/$', 'save', name='world-save'),
url(r'^search/$', 'search', name='world-search'),
```

when i call any url it was going directly url(r'^$', 'index', name = 'world-index') so every time index page was returning. Than i removed '$' from first url than it is ok. İt is working now.

Comment: can you post your urlconf for this view?

Answer (score 2):

What are you expecting it to do? The `print` method outputs the specified text to STDOUT, but in the case of a Django view being served by a webserver, STDOUT is *not* the response to the client; it's your console if running the dev server or perhaps a log file on your production server.

The fact that you're *not* getting errors is far more strange. With a view like this Django should be blowing up saying that no response was returned.

Comment: I agree-- check your shell where you ran `python manage.py runserver`; I'm guessing you'll see 1) your print statement and 2) Django raising an exception

Comment: i was expected to see "Here!" just in console.